# Leaking window, has the seal of flashing failed?

Tags: windows, flashing, window-frame

My tenants have reported leaking from the top of the windows in 2 of the windows at the property. I first thought it was a cavity breach caused by the roof but a roofer said it was okay. I am looking to get the windows replaced but wanted to ask advice on if this is probably the issue. I have attached the pictures. The windows are believed to be 20+ years old so that where by suspicions lie. Water also appears in between the 2 panes as its double glazing. I just want to ensure that even after replacing the windows that the leak will stop.

Cheers

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: that is failed caulking, refresh it

Comment: @asinine by that do you mean sealant on the outside?

Comment: Usually outside, but it will not harm doing the inside